# Where is Qt QOpenGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtopengl

I'm trying to write a C++ application that uses QOpenGLWidget, but Qt Creator gives a "'QOpenGLWidget' file not found" error on this line:

```
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
```

The documentation says QOpenGLWidget was introduced in Qt 5.4, and I believe I am running Qt 5.12.1; `qmake --version` gives:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.12.1 in /home/oreilly/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/gcc_64/lib
```

Moreover, in the Qt Creator menu Tools -> Options... -> Kits also indicates Qt 5.12.1. And Qt Creator allows me to use `#include <QOpenGLWindow>` (also introduced in Qt 5.4 along with QOpenGLWidget), compile and link the OpenGL application without error.

What am I doing wrong? Where is QOpenGLWidget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QOpenGLWidget` is not part of the main QtCore/QtWidgets libraries; rather it is part of a separate (QtOpenGL) library whose headers are in a directory that is not part of the Qt include-path by default.

Fortunately, it's easy to add QtOpenGL's headers to the include-path; just insert the following line into your .pro file:

```
QT += opengl
```

... and then run `qmake` to update your Makefile/Project file, and you should be able to compile using the OpenGL classes.

Comment: My .pro file had this entry: "QT += quick". I assume this explains why qtcreator could find at least QOpenGLWindow. I added "QT += opengl" and now qtcreator finds QOpenGLWidget as well.

Answer (score 1):

At least for Qt 6 for the QOpenGLWidget Class one wants:

> qmake:    QT += openglwidgets

Source: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwidget.html

For the QOpenGLWindow Class  one wants:

> qmake:    QT += opengl

Source: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwindow.html